# Refreshing data in datagridview and picture box at same time C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, refresh, picturebox

Quick question....

On my main form is a datagridview populated using tableadapter.  on my form2 it inserts data (including a picture stored as binary data)into the database table the datagridview is tied to.

On main form there is a refresh button that will re fill the datagridview.  This is where my problem starts.  I have a picture box and when I select a row it will display the photo for that entry stored in the database.  However I have the picture box bound via the designer using:

```
 this.selectedFirearmPictureBox.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("image", this.firearmsTableBindingSource, "image", true));
```

When I refresh the data, all is well except the picture box no longer updates when I select other rows.  If I close the application and run debugger again it works fine.  Could it be that I need to refresh the binding source?

Comment: when you select a row in the grid try setting the position of the bindingsource.

Comment: I have been looking at that for a minute or two now.  Can you elaborate a little or provide a brief example?

Comment: there you go,please check the answer to know if it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your picturebox is bound to the whole bindingsource and not to 1 item,you need to adjust the bindingsource position so the picturebox can update,like this(this is one way):

```
private void dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    firearmsTableBindingSource.Position = e.RowIndex;
}
```

The `RowHeaderMouseClick` event fires when you select a row with the header,and that should fix your problem.

Comment: This I believe it going in the right direction.  however when I remove the databind that bound the picture box to the whole source and put in your code above, nothing happens.

Comment: you dont remove the bind just add the event handler for RowHeaderMouseClick and place this code there,leave the picturebox binding there.the solution i presented is not for replacing the picturebox binding with this handler,its to keep the picturebox binding  and add this code.

Comment: Terry.  I love you.  Worked like a charm!  Answer might have been a no brainer, but for someone new to C# trying to learn this was awesome.  Marked as answer.